# Cannot install gazebojs. Getting NPM errors during installation

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, gazebo-simu

I have been trying to use the Gazebo simulator on Mac. I have been able to install the prerequisites as mentioned here: [Gazebo installation on Mac](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gazebojs_install_mac&cat=gazebojs)
I am just not able to install GazeboJs. When I use the following command in terminal: `npm install gazebojs --save`, I'm getting npm error code 1. I have checked other pages with similar titles & have also followed the usual procedures of:

```
npm cache clean 
npm install
```

But still, getting the same error.
Here's the error output:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/local/ardupilot_gazebo/build/ardupilot_gazebo/build/gz_node_inst/node_modules/gazebojs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! fs.js:45
npm ERR! } = primordials;
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
npm ERR!     at fs.js:45:5
npm ERR!     at req_ (/Users/local/ardupilot_gazebo/build/ardupilot_gazebo/build/gz_node_inst/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
npm ERR!     at Object.req [as require] (/Users/local/ardupilot_gazebo/build/ardupilot_gazebo/build/gz_node_inst/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/local/ardupilot_gazebo/build/ardupilot_gazebo/build/gz_node_inst/node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
npm ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/local/.npm/_logs/2021-06-15T06_56_17_938Z-debug.log
```

Thanks for helping!